# use session with silverlight4 application

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to use session with my silverlight4 application to store data for temporary period . 
So how to use Session with silverlight4 Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight runs on the client.  You don't mention whether you are simply looking at storing data on the clients or whether you want to implement server side session.  If you want to store data on the client have a look at Isolated Storage.  Silverlight uses Isolated Storage as a virtual file system to store data in a hidden folder on the client machine.

Is your Silverlight app calling WCF services hosted in IIS?  If so, and as long as your WCF services opt in for ASP.NET compatibility mode, ASP.NET session is available to you.  With ASP.NET session you get the ability to set expiration times, dependencies etc.